# How to find overlapping substructure exists or not

Tags: python, recursion

I am currently working on an assignment:

> Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return true if nums has a continuous subarray of size at least two whose elements sum up to a multiple of k, or false otherwise.

Which I solved with the following code:

```py
class Solution:
    def helper(self,nums,k,crntsum,crntlen):
        if crntsum % k==0 and crntlen>1:
            return True
        if len(nums)<=0:
            return False
       return self.helper(nums[1:],k,0,0) or self.helper(nums[1:],k,crntsum+nums[0],crntlen+1)
        
    def checkSubarraySum(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> bool:
        return self.helper(nums,k,0,0)
```

Actually, this is the recursive way to solve the problem.

Is there any memorization that can be done for this?
If so, how can we identify that a problem has overlapping sub problems. Is it possible to use DFS for that?

NB: I am aware of the prefix sum solution to this problem.

Comment: This looks like an interview question, and I don't think your solution works. The first recursion branch in the `or` statement will never return `True`, because `crntlen` is always 0. The second branch keeps chopping at the left hand side of the array, so will return `True` only for the prefix subarray that satisfies the condition. You are ignoring the subarrays that are not prefixes of `nums` (i.e. start in the middle of `nums`)

Comment: You say you know about the prefix sums - so that's memorization right there for you. Prefix sums works in linear time (in the worst case) with a memory overhead of `k`, or in quadratic time if `k` is too large and you don't want to allocate extra memory. Not sure what else you are looking for.